# pdfkit - returns a blank pdf with only requested URL

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to render a webpage with pdfkit

My code:

```
import pdfkit
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf')
pdfkit.from_string('http://stackoverflow.com', 'so.pdf', configuration=config)
```

But this just returns a blank pdf with the requested URL at the top.

When in terminal I run wkhtmltopdf directly...

`wkhtmltopdf http://stackoverflow.com so2.pdf`

It renders fine

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with me:

```
>>> import pdfkit
>>> pdfkit.from_url('http://stackoverflow.com', 'out.pdf')
```

What is your `pdfkit` and `wkhtmltopdf` version?

If your job is only calling one simple page, you can also do something like directly:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('wkhtmltopdf http://stackoverflow.com out.pdf')
```

Comment: got it...I was doing `pdfkit.from_string` when I needed `pdfkit.from_url`