# Python xhtml2pdf table cell text display to vertical

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

Im using xhtml2pdf to generate report in django and i would like to let one of my cells text display vertically but i couldn't make it using css.

Here is some attempt:

```
.vertical-text {
     writing-mode: tb-rl; 
}

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="vertical-text" >V text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> UPDATE

`writing-mode` property is missing in the [supported css properties](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/source/reference.rst#supported-css-properties). Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another work around, where we can use css: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nagtan3/hfs4r5j4/521/)

```
.verical-text {
    width:1px;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* this is for displaying whitespaces including Firefox */
}
```

But, there are couple of downfall's here:

1. Is there has to be **spaces between letters** to ensure it's displayed in vertical.
2. The letters are **not rotated**, but would be in similar orientation.

I would suggest use some other tool, where you would not be restricted with css properties like:

- [PDFKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235759/pdfkit-returns-a-blank-pdf-with-only-requested-url)
- [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) - Write a custom nodeJs server in the backend which would do it.

Comment: That laid back though, it wont be possible in my case but all your suggestion is a nodejs right? is there not any 3rd party python plugins that provide a less css restriction for pdf? what do you think about weasyprint? i havent ask anything about it so far.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab There are some python based 3rd party libs as well, as you mentioned, [Weasyprint](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#css-transforms-module-level-1) does provide you the option to transfer and rotate the text (which the modern browsers do support). [PDFKit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit) also has a python implementation.

Comment: ill try it both

Comment: does PDFKIT works on windows machine? im developing on win os

Comment: It seems like, they do support, in a different manner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661876/python-configure-pdfkit-on-windows

Comment: hi there i use PDFKIT it was easy and smooth

Comment: It helps me a lot with PDFKIT and If you add a PDFKIT installation and usage approach ill reward it with my bounty.

Comment: I don't have windows machine, due which I can't vouch for the installation as I am guessing it's `pip install pdfkit` and need to install [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) would do. With that said, the usage is very simple and written in [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit)